# Accessing a function inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-call

I am working on the following code and want to access OutEdgeCount from another function. I tried initializing Gate gate and then using gate.OutEdgeCount() and also
Gate *gate. Both of the above initializations produced an error. I am new to C++. It would be really helpful, if someone could help me or point out any resource which I could refer.

```
template <typename delay_type, typename error_type, typename power_type, typename   mask_type>
class Gate: public Gate_Type<delay_type, error_type, power_type, mask_type>
{
public:
    vector<delay_type> delay;
    vector<error_type> error_probability;
    power_type power;
    vector<mask_type> mask;

    //Constructor
    void GateCopy(Gate<delay_type, error_type, power_type, mask_type> &gate)
    {
        this->gate_name = gate.gate_name;
        this->inout_port_list = gate.inout_port_list;
        this->in_port_list = gate.in_port_list;
        this->out_port_list = gate.out_port_list;
        this->first_in_edge = NULL;
        this->first_out_edge = NULL;
        this->delay.clear();
        this->error_probability.clear();
        this->power = 0;
        this->mask.clear();
        this->parent_block_index = 0;   //the index in sub block list all
        this->active = gate.active;
    }

    int OutEdgeCount(vector<int> out_degree_vec)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Edge<delay_type, error_type> *p_edge = this->first_out_edge;
        if(p_edge == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while(p_edge != NULL)
            {
                if(out_degree_vec.at(p_edge->head_index) != -1)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                p_edge = p_edge->same_tail_next;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
void FindAllPaths()
{
   Gate gate;
   ...
 }
```

Error is as follows-

```
graph.h:227:6: error: ‘template<class delay_type, class error_type, class power_type, class mask_type> class graph_space::Gate’ used without template parameters
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
graph.h: In member function ‘void graph_space::Path<delay_type, error_type, power_type, mask_type>::FindAllPaths(graph_space::Graph<delay_type, error_type, power_type, mask_type>&)’:
graph.h:1797:11: error: missing template arguments before ‘gate’
graph.h:1797:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘gate’
graph.h:1895:39: error: ‘gate’ was not declared in this scope
graph.h:1930:38: error: ‘gate’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: This does not show your error or where the error is generated (I imagine that this is why you are getting downvotes). There is no attempts at initialising anything in this code. Please show `your code` and `the error text`.

Comment: Hope that does it. Please let me know if you want me to add anything else to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to instantiate a template type, you must provide the template parameters for the instance. For example when you create a `std::map<K, V>` then you must provide the types for `K` and `V` i.e. `std::map<std::string, Foo> allTheFoo;`.

So for your example

```
Gate<Milliseconds, Exception, Cube, LowerQuadMask> gate;
```

Of course I have just made up the names of the template types here.

Comment: I had actually done that but I still had an error. Though I believe that was because of the attributes I was passing